# Use Main function in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to use a main function in vb to tell the compiler witch form will load accruing to sql table but some error appear in the class vb which I create it :

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class main
    Dim sqlcnx As New SqlConnection

    Dim dtb As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
   sqlcnx.ConnectionString = "Data Source=HADY-PC\HADI;Initial Catalog=db1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234"


    Dim da As New DataSet1TableAdapters.UserTableAdapter
        dtb.Columns.Add("UserID", GetType(Integer))
        da.FillBy(dtb)
    Dim i As Integer
        MsgBox(dtb.Rows.Count)
         i=dtb.Rows.Count
        If i = 1 Then
            Form1.Show()
        End If
End Class
```

The error is  `Deceleration expected` on msgbox and form1.show
and on if statment :`statemnet cannot appear outside of method body multiline/lambada`

EDIT :

```
Private Sub login_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim da As New DataSet1TableAdapters.UserTableAdapter
    dtb.Columns.Add("UserID", GetType(Integer))
    da.FillBy(dtb)
    Dim i As Integer
    MsgBox(dtb.Rows.Count)
    If i = 1 Then
        Form1.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

the code was like this but when the compile go to the line  `da.FillBy(dtb)` it load the current the login form he not go to the if statement

Comment: Code cannot be placed just anywhere.  It needs to be inside methods (Sub or Function).  That code has no "home" so how would it ever be invoked?   It is not a "Main Function" - you created a Main Class (bad choice of name too)

Comment: What is supposed to determine if Form1 is shown?  We have no idea what `i` represents

Answer (score 2):

You can't run an if statement or show a messagebox outside of a sub. Put it all inside the sub that handles `Form1.Load()` and you should be good to go.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim da As New DataSet1TableAdapters.UserTableAdapter
    dtb.Columns.Add("UserID", GetType(Integer))
    da.FillBy(dtb)
    Dim i As Integer
    MsgBox(dtb.Rows.Count)
    If i = 1 Then
        Form1.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I write this code before but when the compiler go to line  `da.FillBy(dtb)` the current form load before it go to if statement to load the another form

Comment: If it's your main form, then of course it will load... I don't know that there's any way to stop that, aside from maybe running `Me.Opacity = 0` before doing anything else - either way you would start the application, and the application would be running, but the user would have no interface. I don't think that's what you're looking for, unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: Also: See @LarsTech's and @Plutonix's comments. You have created `i`, but not given it a value, so your If statement will never run because `i` has no value, and therefore does not equal 1. I'm assuming you want `Dim i As Integer = dtb.Rows.Count` before your If statement?